# A question about the proof of a theorem in representation theory

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

My question is about some parts of the proof of Theorem 8.1.10 from the book "A Course in the Theory of Groups" by Derek J.S. Robinson.
[image]

To prove Theorem 8.1.10, we want to prove that there is a series of FG-submodules $0=V_1 \le V_2 \le ... \le V_k=V$  such that G operates trivialy on $\frac{V_{i+1}}{V_i}$.
In the proof of this theorem, we see that if $F$ be algebraically closed, by theorem 8.1.9 it can be seen that $\vert G \vert=1$ and obviously, we have the desirable series and G operates trivialy on $\frac{V_{i+1}}{V_i}$. 
Now suppose that $F$ is not algebraically closed and write $\overline{F}$ for its algebraic closure.
My question is about this part of the theorem.

The author mentioned that "By the last paragraph there is a series of $\overline{F}G$-modules $0=\overline{V}_0 \le \overline{V}_1 \le ... \le \overline{V}_k=\overline{V}$ with $\frac{\overline{V}_{i+1}}{\overline{V}_i}$ a trivial module."
I don't know how the last paragraph leads us to that "$\frac{\overline{V}_{i+1}}{\overline{V}_i}$ is a trivial module". Is it true that $G$ is unipotent again on $\overline{F}$?

If $G$ is unipotent on $\overline{F}$, since $\overline{F}$ is algebraically closed, by Theorem 8.1.9 we have $\vert G \vert=1$ and so $G=\{I\}$. I don't understand if this argument is true, why we have to show that "there is a series of $\overline{F}G$-modules $0=\overline{V}_0 \le \overline{V}_1 \le ... \le \overline{V}_k=\overline{V}$ with $\frac{\overline{V}_{i+1}}{\overline{V}_i}$ a trivial module", and we cannot say that $G=\{I\}$ is obviously conjugate to a subgroup of $U(n,F)$.

Comment: I don't see the problem. In the second paragraph, the result is proved for algebraically closed fields. If every element of $G$ is unipotent,  it can be represented as an upper unitriangular matrix over $F$, which is also upper unitriangular over $\overline{F}$. So you can apply the result for algebraically closed fields  to deduce that $\overline{F}G$-module $\overline{V}$ has the claimed series of submodules. And it is not necessarily true that $G=\{ I \}$. That is only true if $G$ acts irreducibly.

Comment: @DerekHolt : Thank you so much because of your comment. We want to prove that $G$ in conjugate to a subgroup of $U(n,F)$, but I don't understand why you said that, "If every element of $G$ is unipotent, it can be represented as an upper unitriangular matrix over F". I understand that in the second paragraph, if we assume that $G$ is irreducible, we have $\vert G \vert=1$ and we have the claimed series. But I don't understand the third paragraph and its relation with the second paragraph and the sentence "By the last paragraph there is a serie...".

Comment: What is your definition of a unipotent element?

Comment: According to the Robinson's book, "An element $g$ of $GL(n,F)$ is termed unipotent if $(g-1)^m=0$ for some $m>0$".

Comment: In that case it seems completely clear that if $g$ is unipotent as an element of ${\rm GL}(n,F)$ then it is also unipotent as an element of ${\rm GL}(n,\overline{F})$, So in the third paragraph he is just using the result that he has already proved (in the second paragraph) for algebraically fields to deduce the existence of the series $\overline{V}_i$.

Comment: Thank you so much because of your helpful comments. My question is absolutely about this part. In the second paragraph, he proved that if the field is algebraically closed, then $\vert G \vert=1$ and so, the series exists. Are you mean that since $\overline{F}$ is algebraically closed, then we have $\vert G \vert=1$ by the second paragraph? I think that this is the result of the second paragraph, but in the third paragraph, I don't understand why we have to continue the proof if $\vert G \vert=1$ as a subgroup of $GL(n,\overline{F})$.

Comment: As I said before he didn't prove that $|G|=1$ in the second paragraph. That wa sonyl for irreducible $G$.

Comment: I got the point. Thank you so much.